# Undefined reference to second function

Tags: c++, gcc, declaration, extern

Have following header (and correspondent cpp) in project:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#ifndef STRINGWORK_H
#define STRINGWORK_H

using namespace std;

vector<string> split(const string& str, const string &delimiters = " ");
string trim(string &str);

#endif // STRINGWORK_H
```

Building project returns linker error:

> file.cpp:21: error: undefined reference to `trim(std::string&)'

if I add `extern "C"` to 2nd function, project builds fine. If I also add `extern "C"` to first function, get linker error again but for the 1st function:

> file.cpp:16: error: undefined reference to `split'

What is the problem here? How to correctly declare such functions?

[What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/630169) - does not explain things, and does not help as here we have C/C++ mixed code.

Comment: You should not use `using namespace std;` in a header file.  Also see: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: No, this does not affect things here.

Comment: I know that.  I was just telling you you should not do that.  It is bad practice and can lead to some interesting compiler errors.

Comment: vote to reopen as suggested things does not cover this case, suggested things do not help.

Comment: Could you post the CPP file? Do you add 'extern "C"' to the function definitions in the CPP file as well?

Comment: No, I had not. Added now, builds fine. Thanks. Good to add above comment to the answer.